# How do I render into a gtk3 statusicon using cairo in a haskell application?

Tags: haskell, gtk3, cairo, gtk2hs

I would like render into the [statusicon](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Display-StatusIcon.html) of my application.

I know I can make the statusicon display a pixbuf by setting [statusIconPixbuf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Display-StatusIcon.html#v:statusIconPixbuf).

And I can create an empty pixbuf via [pixbufNew](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Gdk-Pixbuf.html#v:pixbufNew)  and do things like filling it with a single color.

But how do render into that pixbuf using cairo?

Or is pixbuf not the right thing to use? Is there a better way to render into the statusicon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Pixbuf` i need a way to render into it.

The following solution takes a cairo Rendering `render :: Render a`
and the desired X and Y dimension of the (square) `Pixbuf` (You can change this if you need to create non-square Pixbufs.)

```hs
import qualified Foreign.Ptr as Pointer
import qualified ByteString as B

renderPixbuf :: Int -> Render a -> IO Pixbuf
renderPixbuf size render = withImageSurface FormatARGB32 size size $ \surface -> do
    renderWith surface render
    stride <- imageSurfaceGetStride surface
    surfaceData <- swapRB stride <$> imageSurfaceGetData surface
    B.useAsCStringLen surfaceData $ \(pointer, _) -> do 
      let pointer' = Pointer.castPtr pointer
      pixbufNewFromData pointer' ColorspaceRgb True 8 size size stride
```

It uses the function [withImageSurface](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.3.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#v:withImageSurface) to create a surface for cairo to render to and then calls [renderWith](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.3.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#v:renderWith) to do the actual rendering specified by `render`.

The next two lines extract the image stride, i.e. the number of bytes in a line and the actual image data as ByteString.

`swapRB` is a function that transforms the ByteString because somehow the red and blue channel are in the wrong order. See below for how this is done.

In [B.useAsCStringLen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html) it gets low-level: It taks the ByteString returned by [imageSurfaceGetData](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.3.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#v:imageSurfaceGetData) and converts it to a `Ptr CUChar` to create a new Pixbuf using [pixbufNewFromData](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Gdk-Pixbuf.html#v:pixbufNewFromData).

That's it.

`swapRB` is defined as follows:

```hs
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Data.List (unfoldr)

splitAtIfNotNull :: Int -> B.ByteString -> Maybe (B.ByteString,B.ByteString)
splitAtIfNotNull i string 
  | B.null string = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just $ B.splitAt i string 

mapChunks :: (B.ByteString -> B.ByteString) -> Int -> B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
mapChunks mapper chunkSize = B.concat . map mapper . unfoldr (splitAtIfNotNull chunkSize)

swapRB :: Int -> B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
swapRB = mapChunks swapRBforLine
  where swapRBforLine :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
        swapRBforLine = mapChunks (B.pack . swapRBforPixel . B.unpack) 4 
        swapRBforPixel :: [Word8] -> [Word8]
        swapRBforPixel [b,g,r,a] = [r,g,b,a]
        swapRBforPixel other = other
```

It splits the ByteString of pixeldata into lines, then splits the lines into pixels each consisting of 4 bytes: one byte each for the channels red, green, blue, alpha. Innermost is the actual swapping:

```hs
swapRBforPixel [b,g,r,a] = [r,g,b,a]
```